# Sessions are not working when the site is called by an iframe

Tags: php, session, iframe

I have a first site https://www.mydomain1.com in which I use PHP sessions. No problem, everything works fine, when I go from page to page, I can access my session variables.

I have a second site https://www.mydomain1.com in which I display part of my 1st site via an iframe:

```
<iframe src = "https://www.mydomain1.com" width = "100%" frameborder = "0" style = "border: 0" allowfullscreen = "allowfullscreen" id = "frameLeonard"> </iframe>
```

And there strangely, the session variables are no longer recognized. I'm not even trying to get my 1st site to access the session variables from the 2nd site (that's not the goal and it's normal that it doesn't work) but just run the 2nd site inside the 1st site.

Strangely, it was still working a year ago.
Has there been any upgrade that would explain the problem?

Thank you in advance for your lights !

Comment: What does not work anymore ? Are you sure it is not simply that the session has not been started on the "second site" ?

Comment: The session starts well on the second site when it is run live without the iframe. However, when it is called by the iframe, the session does not start. After checking, the problem exists on Chrome but not on Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Now I found the reason, chrome shows this behaviour. With version 80 (Feb. 2020) it has it's "SameSite by default cookies" enabled as default, which means that including external pages (different domain) inside an iframe, will kill their sessions.

For preventing this, you can disable "SameSite by default cookies" in chrome://flags
Beware: This might be a security issue (but solved my problem for now)

Otherwise - if using PHP 7.3 or newer - you could add one (or both) of the following `ini_set()` in your PHP before `session_start()`:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
session_set_cookie_params(['samesite' => 'None']);
```

Here you get further details:
https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie#prepare-for-chrome-80-updates

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Looks like this works on Firefox but not on Chrome, and only when working on a local server. Couldn't find the `SameSite by default cookies` you mentioned though. I'll just use Firefox for this local development.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you use MySQL function for that,

// to add captcha record via img file.

> ```
> $time = time();
> $deltime = time()-1500;
> $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
>
>     $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `captcha` WHERE `ip` = '" . $ip . "'");
>     if (($result) && ($result->num_rows >= 1))
>     { 
>         $conn->query("UPDATE `captcha` SET `captcha` = '".$_SESSION["captcha"]."' WHERE `ip` = '".$ip."'");
>   }
>   else 
>   {
>       
> $conn->query("DELETE FROM `captcha` WHERE `time` < '".$deltime."'");
>       
> $sql = "INSERT INTO `captcha` (captcha, ip, time) VALUES ('".$_SESSION["captcha"]."', '".$ip."', '".$time."')";
>
> if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
>   //echo "New record created successfully";
> } else {
>   //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
> }
>   }
> ```

// on process file to match captcha code

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `captcha` WHERE `ip` = '" . $ip . "'");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{ 
     $captcha = $row['captcha'];
}
if ($captcha == $_POST["access_token"]) { /* do anything */ }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Having the same problem here, but no solution yet.
I made several tests. Seems only to occur, when iFrame loaded content is SSL certificated. If not, it works perfect.
Maybe this is helpful. Or did you get any solution yet?