# PHP Session data doesn't pass in Chrome or Edge iframes

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, iframe

I have a membership application with several pages that needs to run in an iframe. When you log in you are taken to a membership page with a session variable set to show you are logged in, for instance. All works fine in all browsers when the pages are in a top window. But inside an iframe, session variables are not passed in Chrome, Edge, or iOS Safari. They pass just fine in Firefox, however. What must I do to make sessions work in an iframe in all browsers?

I've put together a demo using the example code from the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). Try them in different browsers.

[Code in Top Window](https://www.tourdeforce360.com/test/sessions/page1.php)

[Code in iframe](https://www.scottwitte.com/test/sessions.html)

Code for Page 1:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Welcome to page #1<br>';

$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
$_SESSION['time']     = time();

// Works if session cookie was accepted
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a><br>';

// Or maybe pass along the session id, if needed
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php?' . SID . '">page 2</a><br><br>';

echo "SID: ".SID;
?>
```

Code for Page 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Welcome to page #2<br /><br>';

echo $_SESSION['favcolor']."<br>"; // green
echo $_SESSION['animal']."<br>";   // cat
echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time'])."<br><br>";

// You may want to use SID here, like we did in page1.php
echo '<a href="page1.php">page 1</a><br><br>';

echo "SID: ".SID;
?>
```

The PHP Manual seems to suggest that there should be a session ID set but I don't think there is. Could that be the problem? A comment in the Page 1 codes says, "Works if session cookie was accepted." I'm guessing it isn't in a Chrome iframe. Any way to get it accepted? Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: why are you using an iframe and not and include?

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65216475/4086612

> Otherwise - if using PHP 7.3 or newer - you could add one (or both) of
> the following ini_set() in your PHP before session_start():

```
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
session_set_cookie_params(['samesite' => 'None']);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that solution, Joe. For me, it didn't work until I changed the second line to:
`session_set_cookie_params(['samesite' => 'None', 'secure' => true]);`
But.... still doesn't help much as it doesn't work for any mobile browser.

Comment: Maybe consider moving to an Ajax solution, where these are divs instead of iframes, and you reload the content dynamically. Laravel Livewire is an interesting approach as well, that reflects the single-page application approach (similar to what you get with the more popular Angular, Vue, or React), but perhaps a lower level of complexity in implementation.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, @Joe. Ajax isn't in my skill set, yet, but may be worth a look. Right now I'm thinking of just passing the data in query strings. That seems to work in all circumstances.

Comment: You'll be happy to discover that it's actually quite straightforward! :) Here's a snippet that will demonstrate the ease:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load